# How to get full information about the bridges?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bridge, libvirt

I have many bridges on my laptop,Ubuntu 22.04

```
ip link show type bridge
```

shows

```
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:53:00:0a:c6:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: mpqemubr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:53:00:83:b8:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-9910826e1e83: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:32:22:ee:e6:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-9ceb855c322b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:32:58:1c:77:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: br-f6d0af00ea88: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
```

I tried

```
ip link xstats type bridge
virbr0          
                    IGMP queries:
                      RX: v1 0 v2 0 v3 0
                      TX: v1 0 v2 0 v3 0
                    IGMP reports:
                      RX: v1 0 v2 0 v3 0
                      TX: v1 0 v2 0 v3 0
                    IGMP leaves: RX: 0 TX: 0
                    IGMP parse errors: 0
                    MLD queries:
                      RX: v1 0 v2 0
                      TX: v1 0 v2 0
                    MLD reports:
                      RX: v1 0 v2 0
                      TX: v1 0 v2 0
                    MLD leaves: RX: 0 TX: 0
                    MLD parse errors: 0
```

I do not understand output.
How to get info about interfaces and how the bridge was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get info about interfaces and how the bridge was created?

You cannot get information about "how the bridge was created" (that is, there's no way to tell if the bridge was created by libvirt, by docker, by netplan, by manual commands, etc, other than recognizing certain naming conventions).

You can get a list of links attached to a bridge with the `ip` command. To show all bridge links:

```
$ ip link show type bridge_slave
```

To show links associated with a particular bridge:

```
$ ip link show type bridge_slave master virbr0
```

You can get more information about a bridge (or other interface) by using the `-d` (`-details`) option; compare:

```
$ ip link show virbr0
49: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c5:a4:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

With:

```
$ ip -d link show virbr0
49: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c5:a4:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0  allmulti
    0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535 bridge forward_delay 200 hello_time 200 max_age
    2000 ageing_time 30000 stp_state 1 priority 32768 vlan_filtering 0
    vlan_protocol 802.1Q bridge_id 8000.52:54:0:c5:a4:f7 designated_root
    8000.52:54:0:c5:a4:f7 root_port 0 root_path_cost 0 topology_change 0
    topology_change_detected 0 hello_timer    0.87 tcn_timer    0.00
    topology_change_timer    0.00 gc_timer  268.85 vlan_default_pvid 1
    vlan_stats_enabled 0 vlan_stats_per_port 0 group_fwd_mask 0 group_address
    01:80:c2:00:00:00 mcast_snooping 1 no_linklocal_learn 0 mcast_vlan_snooping
    0 mcast_router 1 mcast_query_use_ifaddr 0 mcast_querier 0
    mcast_hash_elasticity 16 mcast_hash_max 4096 mcast_last_member_count 2
    mcast_startup_query_count 2 mcast_last_member_interval 100
    mcast_membership_interval 26000 mcast_querier_interval 25500
    mcast_query_interval 12500 mcast_query_response_interval 1000
    mcast_startup_query_interval 3125 mcast_stats_enabled 0 mcast_igmp_version
    2 mcast_mld_version 1 nf_call_iptables 0 nf_call_ip6tables 0
    nf_call_arptables 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1
    gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 tso_max_size 65536 tso_max_segs 65535
    gro_max_size 65536
```